# Changing sprite after mouse click on collider (working with many colliders and many different sprites)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I won't hide that I am new to the Unity and C#. I am trying to make mini escape game.

**My problem: Changing sprites using colliders works only on one object. After clicking second object it works one time and then either the first and the second object don't work.**

**Description:**
On the main screen I will have many items that are "clickable" and some that are "pickable". I created 2 scripts- one that close up to the clicked item, and second that return to the main view.

Main view looks like that: they are 3 colliders and each one close-up to different view. Colliders are the children of the Background. After close-up I don't want the child colliders of background to be working. Only the collider of the close-up should work.

**So the question:** Am I doing anything wrong? Is there any better method to change sprites after mouse click?

[image: Main view looks like that: they are 3 colliders and each one close-up to different view]
[image]

My code:

First script:

```
public class GetCloser : MonoBehaviour // shows close-up of clicked object
{
    public GameObject Actual, Background;

    void OnMouseDown()
    {

            RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, -Vector2.up);

            if (hit.collider != null)
            {
                Background.SetActive(false);

                Actual.GetComponent<Collider2D>().enabled = true;
                Actual.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().enabled = true;
            }


    }

}
```

Second script:

```
public class ReturnTo : MonoBehaviour //hide the close-up image and return to the background
{
    public GameObject Actual, Background;

 void OnMouseDown()
    {

            RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, -Vector2.up);

            if (hit.collider != null)
            {

                Background.SetActive(true);
                Actual.GetComponent<Collider2D>().enabled = false;
                Actual.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().enabled = false;
            }



    }

}
```

Last script:

```
public class PickUp : MonoBehaviour { //hide clicked object- works every time

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().enabled = true;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void OnMouseDown()
    {

            RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, -Vector2.up);

            if (hit == true && hit.collider != null)
            {
                hit.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().enabled = false;
                Destroy(hit.collider);

            }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So if the issue is the colliders for your main screen still being active after zoom that's simply adding in your first script "zoom script" deactivating the colliders for all background or even just simply turning the gameobjects in the background off, then when you zoom back out simply turn the objects back on or colliders back on depending on which you decided to turn off.

Wait I just reread and realize after you click the first object you are no longer able to get the other objects to react any longer.  Looking over your code it is probably because you are destroying the collider in your third script therefore you are no longer able to "hit" the other objects to trigger the code of a collision.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Third script is attached only to pickable object that should just dissapear from background. So I think it's not a problem. 
To be 100% sure I removed that script from project and the problem still exists.